# Static value on the first date in DAX and normalized values

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I need to plot a report of portfolio values using Excel Powerpivot.
I need to set the value of 100 on the first date of the analysis (any selected dat), and then normalize all other values to this starting fixed value

So for example, if on June, 1, 2016 the actual value is 120 and the value for June, 2 is 130, I would like to plot 100 for June, 1 and 108,33 for june 2 (130*100/120)

Comment: What is the first date of analysis? Is it dynamic based on a filter? How do you know June, 1 value is 120, is there a column that stores that value?

Comment: yes, for each day I have a value. Starting date can be anything a user selects as a time slicer  in excel

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to solve it like follows:

```
First Date in Range:=FIRSTDATE(ALLSELECTED(Data[Date]))

Ratio First Date in Range:=CALCULATE(MIN([Value]);
            FIRSTDATE(ALLSELECTED(Data[Date])) )
           /100

Value Norm:=MIN(Data[Value])/[Ratio First Date in Range]
```